# sum different amounts found in a string and display as one amount in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which stores summary for a particular ID number The value in that summary column look like as below.

"I have made a payment for RX $100 Ovp of $80.54 with a closing balance of 550.30"

I want to separate all the amounts $100, $80.54, 550.30 and add them to one value which is 730.84 in SQL Server. Sometimes there will only one amount some time there will more than 3 amounts so I want to add them all to one value.

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

#### Update: More examples given in comment below Shnugo's answer:

1. FACETS CLAIM 44838388477, CREATED AN OVPYMT OF $101.50, CIGNA PD IN FULL
2. p$35.50-co8475783847788 not ovp dd74747858885 gf not ovp. pt lib is greater then gf payment
3. AFTER ADJUSTMENT OF CLAIM 84736625526747 CREATED AN OVPYMT OF $48.30 (claim facts 746366784993-00)

Comment: We are going to need some table samples.

Comment: Hi MHK, I just added your examples of your comment below to your question. Please check, if this is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try it like this:

Short explanation: First I take away the `$` sign. Your string is then splitted in parts by replacing all spaces with XML end- and start tags. With a start tag in front and a closing tag at the end we can cast this to XML and use the `.nodes()`-method to get the parts as derived table.

Attention: If your string might include forbidden characters (<,> or &), you must replace them with `&lt;`,`&gt;` and `&amp;`.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)='I have made a payment for RX $100 Ovp of $80.54 with a closing balance of 550.30';

WITH Splitted(number) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(part.value('.','varchar(max)') AS DECIMAL(14,4))
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@string,'$',''),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
    ) AS MyString(AsXml)
    CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(part)
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(part.value('.','varchar(max)') )=1
)
SELECT SUM(number) 
FROM Splitted
```

Comment: Only you can know how to distinguish between *real* numbers to sum up and IDs or other stuff... Just add more checks after `WHERE ISNUMERIC(...)` with `AND...`. If your IDs are always of the same length, you might check this. You cannot expect a dumb little query to do magic :-)